# Best practices for passing parameters from one pipeline to another

Tags: spinnaker

We're trying to use spinnaker(with kubernetes/helm) to roll out multiple parameterized stacks and gradually promote the new one in an application where each stack has its own database.

We've divided up the applications into microservices and each one has a deployment pipeline which  is triggered by the dependent pipeline: so it's something like bake and deploy batch job -> start background services -> start user-facing layer

There's a couple parameters we want to pass throughout the process, getting injected at the bake stage to make sure everything is consistently labelled and looking at the right database.

Currently we are using

```
${trigger['parentExecution']['trigger']['parameters']['myParam']}
```

for the next pipeline, and I can only imagine from there it gets uglier with

```
${trigger['parentExecution']['trigger']['parentExecution']['trigger']['parameters']['myParam']}
```

and so on?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I feel that the way you've framed your question makes it opinion-based. "*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*". If you have working code, you could possibly use the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site.

Comment: Well, the current solution is not really tenable. I don't think it's a matter of opinion that a recurring pair of ['trigger']['parentExecution'] at each pipeline stage is hard to understand. What I'm looking for is to know if a) I'm somehow misusing spinnaker or b) there is another mechanism to do this more concisely

Comment: Fair enough - I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, looks like it is a general way - because pipeline itself keeps all execution context.
But you can make trigger in other ways:

- call pipelines directly using "Pipeline" Stage
- call Webhook trigger and pass all reruired parameters

Comment: Right, this is more or less what we ended up doing, sticking a webhook at the end of each stage to call the next.